# SNEP Windows Phone VS SNEP Android and Blackberry

Tags: android, blackberry, windows-phone-8, nfc, apdu

I am trying to send a URL in a NDEF Message from my Computer and ACR 122 to a phone.
To Achieve that, I use SNEP. 
The thing is that it works perfectly with Android and Blackberry, but not with any Windows Phone.

These are the commands I send using the java library Smartcardio, and the responses I got from the phone (android or Windows)

**Command 1 : (configure PN532 as Target)
FF 00 00 00 2D D4 8C 00 08 00 12 34 56 40 01 FE0100000000000000000000000000FFFF01FE01000000000000000646666D01011000**

Response Android : D5 8D 25 1E D4 00 D5 65 D7 84 0E 59 F9 CF B2 BA 00 00 00 32 46 66 6D 01 01 11 03 02 00 13 04 01 96 90 00

Response Windows Phone : D5 8D 05 22 D4 00 C2 65 AD 78 F4 3D 81 F8 72 8F 00 00 00 32 46 66 6D 01 01 11 02 02 03 80 03 02 00 01 04 01 64 90 00

**Command 2 : (tg get data)
FF00000002 D486**

Response Android : D5870000009000

Response WP : D5870000009000

**Command 3 : (tg set data, ndef with "urn:nfc:sn:snep")
FF00000015 D48E 0520060F 75726E3A6E66633A736E3A736E6570**

Response Android : D58F009000

Reponse WP : D58F009000

**Command 4 : (tg get data)
FF00000002 D486**

Response Android : D587 000000 9000

Response WP : D587 00 05 20 02 02 03 80 050105060F75726E3A6E66633A736E3A736E6570 9000

**Command 5 : (tg set data)
FF00000004D48E 0000**

Response Android : D5 8F 00 9000

Response WP : D5 8F 00 9000

**Command 6 : (tg get data)
FF00000002 D486**

Response Android : D587 00 8184 9000

Response WP : D587 00 8184 02020380050105 9000

**Command 7 : (tg set data, ndef with url "journaldugeek.com")
FF00000021 D48E 132000100200000016 D1 01 12 55 01 6A6F75726E616C64756765656B2E636F6D**

Response Android : D58F 00 9000

Response WP : D58F 00 9000

**Command 8 : (tg get data)
FF00000002D486**

Response Android : D587 00 83 44 01 9000

Response WP : D587 00 83 44 01 9000

**Command 9 : (tg set data)
FF00000004D48E0000**

Response Android : D58F009000

Response WP : D58F009000

**Command 10 : (tg get data)
FF00000002D486**

Response Android : D587 00830401108100000000 9000

Response WP : D587 00830401108100000000 9000

**Command 11 : (tg set data)
FF00000005 D48E 136001**

Response Android : D58F009000

Response WP : D58F009000

**Command 12 : (tg get data)
FF00000002D486**

Response Android : D5870000009000

Response WP : D5870000009000

**Command 13 : disconnect?
FF00000004D48E1160**

Response Android : D58F009000

Response WP : D58F009000

**Command 14 : disconnect?
FF00000002D486**

Response Android : D587 0081C400 9000

Response WP : D587 0081C400 9000

You can see that only Command 6 is different for Android and Windows Phone, however the other ones are the sames. The WP basically send a OK Message, but the url is not displayed in a browser on the phone. Does anybody know why, and know if there is another way to do SNEP with APDU Commands so that it works for Android, WP and Blackberry ?

Comment: The communication sequence looks as I would expect it for successful SNEP (botht he Android and the WP8 variants). The difference in command 6 is that WP8 provides information about the MIU (776 byte) and the receive window size (5), which should not matter for your case. THe differnce in command 4 is that the WP8 device also tries to connect a SNEP session, which your implementation simly ignores (though, I assume this is permitted behavior).

Comment: Have you figured this out already? I've got a very similar problem. Thanks